# view cannot cast to linearlayout Drag Drop images from 1 linearlayout to another

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working in xamarin android application.when drag one image from one linearlayout and  drop to another layout remove first  and after drop add to  other layout.
getting error on

`LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)v;`

```
public bool OnDrag(View  v, DragEvent e)
        {
            Drawable enterShape= Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.shape_droptarget);
            Drawable normalShape = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.shape);

            var action = e.Action;
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case DragAction.Started:
                    //do nothing;
                    break;
                case DragAction.Entered:
                    v.SetBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
                    break;
                case DragAction.Exited:
                      v.SetBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                    break;
                case DragAction.Drop:
                    //drop reassign view to viewgroup
                    View view = (View)e.LocalState;
                    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup)view.Parent;
                    owner.RemoveView(view);
                   LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)v;
                    container.AddView(view);
                    view.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    break;
                case DragAction.Ended:
                    v.SetBackgroundDrawable(normalShape); 

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

 public bool OnTouch(View vi, MotionEvent e)
        {
           if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                ClipData data = ClipData.NewPlainText("", "");
                Android.Views.View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(vi);
                vi.StartDrag(data, shadowBuilder, vi, 0);
                vi.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed id field in data variable and access id to get the image then replace with next one.

public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
          //throw new NotImplementedException();
            if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                v.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
                var data = ClipData.NewPlainText("ID", v.Id.ToString());
                //MyShadowBuilder is userdefined Shadow builder class
                Android.Views.View.DragShadowBuilder shadow =new MyShadowBuilder(v);
                v.StartDrag(data, shadow, null, 0);
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        public bool OnDrag(View v, DragEvent e)
        {
           //throw new NotImplementedException();
            v.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
            Drawable enterShape = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.shape_droptarget);
            Drawable normalShape = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.shape);

```
        var action = e.Action;
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case DragAction.Started:
                //do nothing;
                break;
            case DragAction.Entered:
                v.SetBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
                break;
            case DragAction.Exited:
                v.SetBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                break;

            case DragAction.Drop:
                var data = e.ClipData.GetItemAt(0).Text;// Event.ClipData.GetItemAt(0).Text;
                ImageView vtemp = this.FindViewById<ImageView>((int.Parse(data)));
                View V1 = (View)(v);
                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup)v.Parent;
                ViewGroup tempOwner = (ViewGroup)vtemp.Parent;

                tempOwner.RemoveView(vtemp);
                owner.RemoveView(v);
                tempOwner.AddView(v);
                owner.AddView(vtemp);
                break;
            case DragAction.Ended:
                v.SetBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is one more way to solve this problem.

```
            case DragAction.Drop:

                View v1LocalState = (View)e.LocalState;//event argument-e
                LinearLayout v1LinearLay = (LinearLayout)v1LocalState.Parent;
                v1LinearLay.RemoveView(v1LocalState);


                View current = (View)v;//view argument-v
                LinearLayout curLinearLayout =(LinearLayout) current.Parent;
                curLinearLayout.RemoveView(current);

                v1LinearLay.AddView(current);
                curLinearLayout.AddView(v1LocalState);
```